# Gradle task specific dependency

Tags: android, gradle, task

In my Android project i have the following task

```
class GenerateCustomTask extends DefaultTask {
    @Option(option = "flavor", description = "Gradle flavor name for generating task")
    String customFlavor

    @TaskAction
    execute() {
        ...
    }

}

task generateCustom(type: GenerateCustomTask)
```

I need to use **appache common utils** library **in my task, but not in my application code**.

So how do i add this dependency for the task?

**UPDATE 27 04 2020:**
In the app level `build.gradle` file i include the task with:

```
apply from: '../customs/customs.gradle'
```

When i try to add the library to the classpath, i can't import in in my `customs.gradle` file.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `buildscript` block:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    ...
  }
  dependencies {
    ...
    classpath "yourDependency"
  }
}
```

Your dependency will only be available from your build script.

But if your task contains a lot of logic, best way to create custom Gradle Plugin which contains all necessary dependencies and encapsulates logic.

Comment: Is it the only way for doing that?

Comment: Why this method doesn’t suit you? I have written, that you can create standalone gradle plugin as a java module with your dependencies. It will a best way.

Comment: Because the task and it's purpose very simple and i don't want to create plugin for that. May be i am wrong.

Comment: So, just add your dependency to buildscript.dependencies, as I wrote to you.

Comment: When i add dependency to the classpath, i can't import it in the other file with my task. I'll update the question to add these details